# Failed trying to use pytesseract

Tags: python, captcha, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use pytesseract to solve this captcha but haven't got any result yet.

[image: Captcha]

here's the code I use

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

path = 'Captcha.jpg'
img = Image.open(path)
thresh = 200
fn = lambda x: 0 if x>thresh else 255
r = img.convert('L').point(fn, mode='1')
r.save('temp.jpg')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(r)
print(text)
```

It prints nothing.

I'm not sure how image_to_string algorithm works but I think the problem might be because of the angles of the digits and those lines in the background. Is it true? If true, is there any method that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot solve captcha 100% using pytesseract but we can solve this problem using below code

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import pytesseract

def captcha_solution(browser):
    with open('captcha.jpg', 'wb') as file:
        l = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            'Captcha_Image_Xpath')
        file.write(l.screenshot_as_png)

    img = Image.open('captcha.jpg')

    gray = img.convert('L')
    # time.sleep(1)

    path_to_tesseract = r"C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe"
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract
    target = pytesseract.image_to_string(
        gray, lang='eng', config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
    print(target)
    return target


for j in range(1, 6):#As much time you want to try
    cap = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        'Input_Box_Xpath')
    t = captcha_solution(browser)
    action = ActionChains(browser)
    action.double_click(cap).perform()
    cap.send_keys(t)
    if captcha is wrong:
        #check if captcha is wrong
    else:
        #if captcha is correct
        break
```