# how to solve this captcha in python here is the image

Tags: python

[image]

I am expecting to get a plain text digit to enter in captcha using selenium python. note: the captcha contains only numbers.

Comment: In my opinion, help with captcha-cracking should be prohibited here.  It is borderline unethical.  The web site has intentionally added this protection to prevent you from stealing their copyrighted material.

Comment: May my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70592885/failed-trying-to-use-pytesseract/70831578#70831578) helps you.